# Cruise control.NET

Tags: .net, scripting, cruisecontrol

I am just a beginner in cruise control.NET.My doubt is that is there any way by which cruise control.NET can detect changes in the local folder itself(for eg:C:/MYSource)rather than look for changes in the source control repository.I need to force the build all the time from the web dashboard to build.I want cruise control.NET to detect the changes and itself force the build rather than manual interference.This is really important since i am doing for a demo purpose and after the successfull implementation of my demo i would be able to go for source control repository.

Thanks and regards
Maddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can check for changes in a local folder. See: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Filesystem+Source+Control+Block.

In our setup we have two cruisecontrol servers: one that builds the solution, stores the results in a zipfile and copies the zipfile to a share on the second server.
CruiseControl on the second server checks the shared directory for new files and triggers a test proces.